# Different notations of probability

Tags: probability-theory

I have seen probability density functions defined as $p(x)$ or $p_X(x)$ or $f(x)$  or $F'(x)$. What does each of these notations mean in context and when should I use one over another?

Do they all mean the same and exist as functions to begin with?

Comment: Yes, I do mean density function, sorry about the wrong terms.

Comment: $F^{-1}$ doesn't fit, do it?

Comment: I assume and inverse function of F which is the same as F' but maybe some other definition of inverses exist. However, I removed $F^{-1}$.

Comment: $F'$ usually denotes the derivative of $F$ not the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_X(x)$ is the conventional notation for probability density function of the continuous random variable $X$.   Though it can also be so used, $p_X(x)$ is *more often* used for a probability mass function of a discrete random variable, $X$.

$F_X(x)$ is usual notation for a cumulative distribution function.   If the random variable is continuous and real valued, then $F'_X(x)$ is the density function.

When the identity of the random variable is implicitly understood, then it is permissible to omit the identifying subscript.   Many engineering or physics texts feel that lowercase token, $x$, is sufficient to do this.   This may save typesetting but really should not be done when discussing multiple random variables.